# Call to generic function in Swift not compiling when input Array is held in a variable

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to write a generic function that takes in an Array of tuples containing Equatable elements, but it is not compiling when I use a variable (instead of a raw value) as an argument. What is going wrong and what is the correct way to do this?

```
func genericFunction<E: Equatable>(input: [(E,E)]) {
    // Need E to be Equatable for comparison
}

let someArray = [([1,2,3],[2,3,4])]

// Success on this line, even though the array is the same!
genericFunction([([1,2,3],[2,3,4])])

// Error on this line
// "Cannot convert value of type '[(Array<Int>, Array<Int>)]' to expected 
//  argument type '[(_, _)]'"
genericFunction(someArray)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try like this `func genericFunction<E: Equatable>(input: [([E],[E])]) {`

Comment: You are passing the wrong type, should be a tuple of 2 Equatable arrays

Comment: Thank you, I don't necessarily want them to be Arrays though. I would also like to be able to call `genericFunction([(1,2)])`.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused about equatable, but isn't it equatable if `[1,2,3] == [1,2,4]` compiles?

Comment: Yes, it compiles, runs, and returns the expected answer (false in this case).

Comment: I think the problem there it is not any array that it is equatable. If you try to compare two Array of Any it won't compile

Comment: You can compare two Array<Element> only if the element is equatable

Comment: Just tested this code in Playground, I get an error on the first line as well. You're right @LeoDabus, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The first line actually causes a compile error as well- but only in a Swift Playground. Strange and probably an error in Xcode. Regardless, the correct way to do this, while supporting my goal of E not necessarily being an Array, seems to be:

```
func genericFunction<E: Equatable>(input: [([E],[E])]) {
    // Need E to be Equatable for comparison
}

func genericFunction<E: Equatable>(input: [(E,E)]) {
    // Need E to be Equatable for comparison
}

let someArray = [([1,2,3],[2,3,4])]

// Both compile now
genericFunction([([1,2,3],[2,3,4])])
genericFunction(someArray)
```